# MVC5 Compilation Bug

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

The code that I am running is:

```
@if (Model.Criteria != null)
{
    @Html.Raw("<ul>")
  foreach (var value in Model.Criteria.SearchCriteria)
  {
    @Html.Raw("<li>" + value.Key + " - ")

    var test = (Dictionary<string, object>)@value.Value;

    switch (test.First().Key.ToUpper())
    {
        case "DDL":
            <select>
                @foreach (var val in (string[])test.First().Value)
                {
                    <option value="@val">@val</option>
                }
            </select>
            break;
        case "INPUT":
        @Html.TextBox(test.First().Value.ToString())
            break;
    }

    @Html.Raw("</li>")
  }
@Html.Raw("</ul>")
}
```

SearchCriteria is also `Dictionary<string, object>`

If I remove test variable and switch statement, it works without problem.  I'm trying to understand why can't I assign the test as a dictionary object and then loop through it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A "compilation error" is not the same thing as a "compilation bug". I encourage you to retitle your question, as the bug is in your code, not in the compiler or its compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Raw("<li>" + @value.Key + " - ")` should be `@Html.Raw("<li>" + value.Key + " - ")`, because inside the Raw() method, you're already dealing with C# syntax; value.Key is just a string variable.

Same thing with `var test = (Dictionary<string, object>)@value;`.

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggested and I still get the same error.  If I remove the test variable and entire switch statement, the code works and the page loads.  When I introduce the test variable it crashes with that error.

Comment: I just saw the same thing in another place, did you update that too?

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!